# Training CNN on small subsets to select architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Do you know if it's possible to use a very small subset of my training data (100 or 500 instances only for example), to train very rough CNN network quickly in order to compare different architectures, then select the best performing one ?

When I say "possible", I mean is there evidence that applying that kind of selection strategy works, and that the selected network will consistently outperform the other to for this specific task.

Thank you,

For information, the project in question would constist of two stages CNNs to classify multichannel timeseries. The first CNN would forecast the inputs data over the next period of time, then the second CNN would use this forecast and classify the results in two categories.

Comment: Anything is possible.

Comment: If you decrease the size of training data, it will impact the accuracy. For selecting a good model with good hyperparameters, you have to try every combination.

Comment: Sure it will impact accuracy, but I'm more interested in the consitency of the results for each architecture as the number of instances increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you are talking about is actually used in practice. When tuning hyperparameters, a lot of people select a subset of the whole dataset to do this.

Is the best architecture on the subset necessarily the best on the full dataset? **NO**! However, it's the *best guess* you have and that's why it's useful.

---

A couple of things to note on your question:

1. 100-500 instances is **extremely low**! The CNN still needs to be trained. When we say *subset* we usually mean tens of thousands of images (out of the millions of the dataset). If your dataset is under 50000 images then why do you need a subset?  Train on the whole dataset.
2. Contrary to what a lot of people believe, the details of the architecture are of **little importance** to the classification performance. Some of the hyperparameters you mention (e.g. kernel size) are of secondary importance. The key things you should focus on is depth, size of layers, use of pooling/skip connections/batch norm/dropout, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Djib2011, the number was an example i actually have no idea. It would not be images in my case but time series data from sensors sampled every tens of a second. I have roughly a year of data over 5000 sensor for 100 aircrafts. So that's 31 billion instances per sensor. So 50000 would be totally acceptable as a subset.

Comment: Yes, obviously there is a tradeoff between how well your subset architecture generalizes on the full set and how fast it will train... I think somewhere around 50000-100000 is a number where you can ensure that the CNN will be trained properly and run a lot of experiments.